# How to use context parameter in TAC (Talend)?

Tags: talend

I tried to implement context parameter in TAC but its not working for me. Could you please explain with an example?

Comment: Can we see your minimal, relevant code?

Answer (score 1):

Groups of the context parameters could be created in Talend repository:

[image]

After you entered a name of context Group, go to the next step where new variables could be created.
When you done with it. Switch to table view and press "Configure contexts..." button:

[image]

In opened window you can create and manage different contexts, e.g.:

[image]

After adding new contexts you can set different variable values for different contexts:

[image]

When you done with your new context group just add it to your job:

[image]

Now you can use them inside the job.
All this stuff are synchronized with TAC via Talend SVN repository and will be available there after the commit. Then you can choose appropriate context for your job at execution task properties:

[image]

Also, you can override context variables by some custom value using "Context parameters" menu at the bottom of "Job Conductor" page.